# Selenium Internet Explorer Driver Unable to find element (without explicit wait solution)?

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer

Trying to enter text on google and click a button, getting an exception "Unable to find element" on this line: driverIE.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).SendKeys("Selenium"), although I know the element exists on the pages DOM.

**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Code**

```
Imports OpenQA.Selenium
Imports OpenQA.Selenium.IE

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim driverIE As New InternetExplorerDriver()
        driverIE.Navigate.GoToUrl("http://google.com")
        driverIE.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).SendKeys("Selenium")
        driverIE.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter)
    End Sub
End Class
```

***Things I've already tried before posting to SO***

> The IEDriverServer exectuable must be downloaded and placed in your
>   PATH.
>
> On IE 7 or higher on Windows Vista or Windows 7, you must set
>   the Protected Mode settings for each zone to be the same value. The
>   value can be on or off, as long as it is the same for every zone. To
>   set the Protected Mode settings, choose "Internet Options..." from the
>   Tools menu, and click on the Security tab. For each zone, there will
>   be a check box at the bottom of the tab labeled "Enable Protected
>   Mode".
>
> Additionally, "Enhanced Protected Mode" must be disabled for IE 10 and
>   higher. This option is found in the Advanced tab of the Internet
>   Options dialog. The browser zoom level must be set to 100% so that the
>   native mouse events can be set to the correct coordinates.
>
> For IE 11 only, you will need to set a registry entry on the target
>   computer so that the driver can maintain a connection to the instance
>   of Internet Explorer it creates. For 32-bit Windows installations, the
>   key you must examine in the registry editor is
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet
>   Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE. For 64-bit Windows
>   installations, the key is
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet
>   Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE. Please note that the
>   FEATURE_BFCACHE subkey may or may not be present, and should be
>   created if it is not present. Important: Inside this key, create a
>   DWORD value named iexplore.exe with the value of 0.

**Footnote:** This is not a duplicate of this question: [Selenium Unable to Find Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27832266/selenium-unable-to-find-element) The reason being, I do not want to use explicit Wait().  Thanks!

Comment: Set IE security levels to Medium across the board, and it seems to be working.  However, its hitting enter before Selenium has been inserted into the search query textbox.

Comment: Solved the slow typing issue by using IE x86 instead of x64 as suggested here: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/5116

Comment: In point of fact, this question is an exact duplicate of the one you linked to. Same root cause, same solution. The `FindElement` method fails because the element you're looking for isn't in the DOM at the moment the driver is looking for it. Remember that the driver is a lot faster than you are, so manually it might seem obvious the element is there, but to the driver is not. You _have_ to wait for the element to be present. `WebDriverWait` is the best solution to that scenario.